# Disable allow edits in a subform using a checkbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form which displays relevant headings to identify the data about a submission such as name, id and owner etc. From this you can enter into the submission which displays everything in detail about that submission.

I want to implement a checkbox in the original form that will enable/disable if someone is able to make edits to the submission form. I was able to disable the editing function if I were to go into the submission form but I don't know how  would go about doing this without going into the submission form.

So now headings will include name, id, owner and a checkbox to allow editing of submission form.

I tried to explain this as best as I could if you have any questions please ask and thank you.

Comment: You can open the submission form's edit mode based on the value of the checkbox in the original form. Do you open the submission form with a macro or VBA now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *AfterUpdate* event of the checkbox, here named AllowEdits:

```
Me!YourSubformControlName.Form.AllowEdits = Me!AllowEdits.Value
```